# How to put text in rectangle using Matter.js and p5.js

Tags: javascript, text, p5.js, matter.js

I followed this tutorial on how to use matter.js of codetrain.
I was wondering how i could put text in the rectangles?
For now it doesn't really matter what the the text is just as long as i can put text in them in a certain way.

This is what my javascript looks like now
i'm using the matter.js library and p5.js

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

var engine;
var world;
var boxes = [];

var ground;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    engine = Engine.create();
    world = engine.world;
    Engine.run(engine);
    var options = {
      isStatic: true
    }
    ground = Bodies.rectangle(200, height, width, 10, options);
    World.add(world, ground);
  }


function Box(x, y, w, h) {
    this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    World.add(world, this.body);

    this.show = function(){
      var pos = this.body.position;
      var angle = this.body.angle;

      push();
      translate(pos.x, pos.y);
      rotate(angle);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      strokeWeight(1);
      stroke(255);
      fill(0);
      rect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
      pop();
    }
  }

function mousePressed(){
  boxes.push(new Box(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100))
}

  function draw() {
    background(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      boxes[i].show();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use p5js [`text()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text) function for that:

```
this.show = function () {
    var pos = this.body.position;
    var angle = this.body.angle;

    push();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(angle);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(255);
    fill(0);
    rect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    stroke(255);
    // translate(-this.w/2, -this.h/2); // Is you want to move the text at the top left corner
    fill(255);
    stroke(255);
    text("foo", 0, 0);
    pop();
};
```

`text()` takes as parameter the string to draw and its position. Since you already `translate(pos.x, pos.y);` you can simply use `0,0` as the coordinates. You might be interested in [`textWidth()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textWidth) too if at some point you want to center the text.

[Here is a working example](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/vYKwqLX)